# c# error: input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, string, format, dataset

I'm a beginner in c#, currently attempting a windows form project. I've designed a form titled drugform. I use the **dataset** method to connect to the database. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using drugstoreform.BaseInfoTableAdapters;


namespace drugstoreform
{
    public partial class DrugForm : Form
    {

        int Row = -1;
        public DrugForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Register_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            dbm_Medecine db = new dbm_Medecine();

            db.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(DrugCode.Text.Trim()), DrugName.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToString(HowUse.Text.Trim()), Convert.ToDecimal(price.Text.Trim()));

        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {

        }
```

When I click on the register button, I get this error: `input string was not in a correct format`.

Comment: what is the value of `DrugCode.Text` when you click Register button ?

Comment: `DrugCode.Text` and `price.Text` are both assumed to be numeric values.  It's likely that one of them is not.

Comment: The problem is that in one of your conversions on the db.Insert line you are passing in a value which cannot be converted. For example you might be passing a letter into Convert.ToInt32. Output each of your values to a log or MessageBox to see which value is incorrect.

Comment: @Selman22, DrugCode.txt assumed numeric values

Answer (score 0):

You get the error in`Convert.ToInt32` and/or `Convert.ToDecimal` because the input was invalid. You can use `int.TryParse` and `decimal.TryParse` to validate it:

```
int drugCode;
decimal price;
if (int.TryParse(DrugCode.Text.Trim(), out drugCode) && decimal.TryParse(price.Text.Trim(), out price))
{
    db.Insert(drugCode, DrugName.Text.Trim(), HowUse.Text.Trim(), price);
}
```

In the `if` `drugCode` and `price` are initialized with the correct value. Otherwise you should provide an error message that the user should provide correct input.

Possible reasons: perhaps the user enters `2.6` but the computer uses `,` as decimal separator. Or `DrugCode.Text` or `price.Text` are simply empty.

Comment: maybe that will prevent the exception,but it doesn't solve the problem :)

Comment: It _does_, if the user provide proper input. Maybe he's using `2.6` but the computer uses `,` as decimal separator. I don't know. Perhaps a TextBox is simply  empty.